# javascript: a regular expression for "somestring A.B.C(anything can be here)"

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string like, "xyz A.B.C.(anything)" (there's at least one space/tab/newline between z and A.)

I'd like to find "A.B.C".

Comment: See eagle's answer: "...need to be more specific..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
^\w+\s+((?:[A-Z]\.)+).*$
```

Gives the following matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/IQIc2EfV5Y)):

```
matched input        -> group 1 capture
---------------------------------------
xyz A.B.C.whatever   -> A.B.C.
blahblah X.Y.bloop   -> X.Y.
```

If this is not what you want, then go back and forth with me on rubular and we'll develop the pattern together.

Comment: eagle,

Thank you guys, both work, at least in my situation. I forgot to put (?:

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be more specific about what it is you are trying to match exactly.

If it's just letters with a dot followed by them (no whitespace between them), then this will work:

```
/xyz\s+((?:[A-Z]\.)+)/
```

(It will put them in the first back reference (i.e. $1).